# RoundCube not found @ Debian 8 & ISPConfig 3

Tags: mysql, apache, php-7, roundcube, ispconfig

I have installed ISPConfig with Apache via this repo: https://github.com/servisys/ispconfig_setup.

After them i was switch PHP 5.6 to PHP 7 - apps working fine. But roundcube on url: https://IP:8080/webmail missing = 404.

How can I fix it this problem?
What can I try check?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it ...

https://github.com/servisys/ispconfig_setup/issues/145

Is but about bad redirecting with :8080 port.